# ItextSharp - Copy numbering to next page when the column breaks

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, xmlworker

I am using ItextSharp and xmlworker to convert html to pdf and have tables that run across multiple pages. And these tables have serial numbers. So when a table overflows to another page, the column breaks and the serial number stays in the first half. How do I copy the number/data to the cell in the next  page as well.

[This how it's currently rendering. How do I copy the '(c)' to the next page following a page break.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4tQW.jpg)